# Navigation Drawer Activity Error

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I just updated to Android Studio 3.1.2. When i create a navigation drawer activity everything seems to work just fine. But when I go into the activity_main_drawer.xml file (menu folder) it's keep saying waiting for build to finish even after a build has already finished (even after more than 3 builds and runs on my phone). 
Is there any way to solve this and get a preview?

Comment: Post the code here.

Comment: Try invalidate catch and restart

Comment: @Shambhu... This is not any problem of code!

Comment: 90% agree with you. But very few times I've faced the problem of inappropriate structure or invalid params of layout will make a wheel continuous running on the blank preview showing as `waiting for build to finish`.

Comment: But before looking into the code, please try for the `invalidate cache and restart`.

Comment: I tried to invalidate caches and restart. Nothing has changed. Everytime I press on the acitivity_main_drawel.xml and go to the design (even a brand new project) it gives me an error stating "exception in android support".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it after I removed this line from the drawer menu: `tools:showIn="navigation_view"`
Then I rebuilt the project and everything worked fine.

Comment: I guess this kinda fixes the problem. I'm able to see a preview but it's a regular menu instead of what I looks like in the app.